# How do I sync contact lists from outlook.com / Office365 into my Android contacts?

Tags: contacts, outlook, outlook.com

I am successfully syncing my outlook.com and Office365 contacts into my Android contacts (Samsung S9), but I cannot see the contact lists in either account.
How do I sync the contact lists? I would like to use them both from Messages and from Outlook.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Microsoft has a poor implementation of contacts sync and I was never satisfied with it. After hitting my head against a wall for several years, waiting for Microsoft to improve the sync, I've just made the switch to Google Contacts.
Not something that I prefer, but there's no way to have your contact lists or folders synced using any of the official apps. And I have not tried much to rely on a 3rd party app for this purpose.